# Does pointwise convergence of a sequence of functions in each closed subinterval of an open interval imply pointwise convergence in the open interval?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence, sequence-of-function

If a sequence {$f_n$} be uniformly convergent in every closed subinterval $[a+ε,b-δ]⊂(a,b)$, then it isn't necessarily uniformly convergent in $(a,b)$. But what about pointwise convergence? That is, if a sequence {$f_n$} be pointwise convergent in every closed subinterval $[a+ε,b-δ]⊂(a,b)$, is it pointwise convergent in $(a,b)$? {$f_n$} may or may not be uniformly convergent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it is. Pick a point $x \in (a,b)$. The interval being open gives you an $ \epsilon>0 $ such that $(x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon) \in (a,b)$, and clearly this open interval contains the closed interval $[x-\frac{\epsilon}{2},x+\frac{\epsilon}{2}]$.

Answer (score 1):

For each point $x$ in this interval the set $\{x\}$ is a closed subinterval.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $f_n$ is not pointwise convergent. Then there is some point $x_0\in (a,b)$ where the function values $f_n(x_0)$ do not converge as $n\to\infty$. Can you see the contradiction?